# ASP.NET MVC: Can I use the MicrosoftMvcValidation.js functions to make an <input type=file> mandatory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, validation, asp.net-ajax

I have a form with a file-upload button plus some other entry fields and a submit button. I want the submit button to be enabled only if a file has been selected. I could probably do this with JQuery, but I figured that since I'm already including the `MicrosoftMvcValidation.js` scripts there might be something in there that I could use? Anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use ASP.NET MVC, so my answer may be inappropriate.

In WebForms, validators work fine on file inputs. So when I want to block the form submitting if the user hasn't provided a file, I just put a RequiredFieldValidator.

For example, to force the user to submit an image of type GIF/JPG/PNG :

```
<asp:FileUpload id="FileInput" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="FileInput" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="FileInput" ValidationExpression="^.*\.(gif|GIF|jpe?g|JPE?G|png|PNG)$" runat="server" />
```

This does not solve your question about disabling the submit button while a file has not been selected. This jQuery snippet can do the trick :

```
$(function()
{
    $("input:file").change(function()
    {
        var fileName=$.trim($(this).val());
        $("input:submit").prop("disabled")=(fileName.length==0);
    });
});
```

You must ensure that the submit button is initially disabled.